# Extracting specific row from multiple files using loop

Tags: r, loops, extract, rows

I have 18 years of hourly rainfall data. Each CSV file contains a point (latitude and longitude), with corresponding rain rate and gauged-calibrated values. I want to extract the rain rate and gauged-calibrated rain values of a specific coordinate.

1. How can I extract the row of a specific coordinate in R using a loop?
2. How can I merge all the extracted values into one file?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: @magno for example, I want to extract the rain rate (for example: 0.5) and the gauged-calibrated rain (1.5) values of this coordinate 125.55E and 7.15N. After, I extracted the values, I want to combine it in one file for statistical analysis. Thankss

Comment: by example I meant example data and example code (if any tried so far).